# Longest Repeating Subarray (With Overlapping)

Tags: code-golf, restricted-complexity

Earlier I asked about this problem on stackoverflow ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77856631)), but now I also want to see the golfiest solutions

### Problem:

Given an array of arbitrary numbers, what is the longest subarray that is repeated (appears more than once)? In case there are multiple distinct repeated subarrays that all have the longest length, the answer can be any of them. If no subarray appears more than once, the answer is `[]` (the empty array).

Overlapping is allowed, that is partial occurrences of a subarray within itself is allowed. for ex, in the array `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]` the longest repeating subarray is `[1, 2, 1, 2]`. Look here

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
^         ^        occurence #1
       ^        ^  occurence #2
```

### Constraints:

For the sake of code golf simplicity, assume that all values in the array are integers. like a 32bit int data type

The time complexity and the space complexity must be \$O(n^{2 - \varepsilon})\$ where \$n\$ = length of array, for some \$\varepsilon > 0\$.

### Test cases:

| Array | Result |
| --- | --- |
| [1, 2, 5, 7, 1, 2, 4, 5] | [1, 2] |
| [9, 7, 0, 1, 6, 3, 6, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 8, 3, 6, 1, 6, 3] | [1, 6, 3] |
| [1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 0, -1, 7, 0, -1] | [7, 0, -1] |
| [1, 1, 1, 1] | [1, 1, 1] |
| [1, 1, 1] | [1, 1] |
| [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5] | [2] |
| [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] | [] |
| [1, 6, 2, 1, 6, 2, 1, 5] | [1, 6, 2, 1] |

Also this JS code generates a large test case with an array of one hundred thousand elements which your program should be able to handle. The answer is [1, 2, 3, ..., 100] (the 100 consecutive integers from 1 to 100)

```
function make_case() {
    let array = [];
    let number = 200;
    for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        array.push(number); array.push(number);
        number++;
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        array.push(i);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 1700; i++) {
        array.push(number); array.push(number);
        number++;
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        array.push(i);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < (100_000 - 500 * 2 - 100 - 1700 * 2 - 100) / 2; i++) {
        array.push(number); array.push(number);
        number++;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Nice first challenge! Does lower than \$O(n^2)\$ mean strictly lower (\$o(n^2)\$)? You might want \$O(n^{2-\varepsilon})\$, unless you are ok with \$O(\frac{n^2}{\log n})\$. Are hashing-based solutions (which are only correct with high probability) ok?

Comment: @CommandMaster Sorry could you explain what n^(2-epsilon) means there and how the meaning changes? I'm looking for solutions that are accurate, not based on probability, but I'm open to changing that. Thanks for feedback!

Comment: \$n^{2-\varepsilon}\$ means that there must be some \$\varepsilon>0\$ such that the solution is \$O(n^{2-\varepsilon})\$. This is just a bit tighter than \$o(n^2)\$, as it prevents things like \$O(\frac{n^2}{\log n})\$

Comment: @CommandMaster I think I get it, I'll edit

Comment: For complexity reason are all numbers O(n)?

Comment: @l4m2 Like for space complexity? If using a fixed size integer type then each integer take O(1) space. Or maybe you're asking about time complexity of integer operations?

Comment: I ask number range in case someone make `Arr[max(A)-min(A)+1]`

Comment: @l4m2 Oh numbers in the array can be any integer that fits in a 32bit signed integer data type (or the closest equivalent if there is no datatype large enough)

Comment: So is it \$\text O\left(1\right)\$?

Comment: @l4m2 no I wouldn't say so, that's too much of a simplification. I just set it to fixed size integer for simplicity (not requiring support for bigints or anything), but the range of integers doesn't depend on the size of the array at all and I believe the solution should not depend on the numbers inside, if we just assume each individual number takes O(1) space. like theoretically the solution should be adaptable to a larger integer type by just changing the types of the variables used without readjusting any logic

Answer (score 4):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>378</s> <s>360</s> <s>359</s> <s>339</s> 337 bytes, \$O(n \sqrt{n} \log^2 n)\$

```cpp
#import<bits/stdc++.h>
using V=std::vector<int>;V f(V a){int l=0,r=a.size(),n,j,i=0,m,L=r,s=sqrt(r);std::map<V,int>M;V v(L),x;for(;i+s<L;)v[i++]=M[x]=M[x=V(&a[i],&a[i+s])]?:~i;for(;M.clear(),l<r;l>m?:r=m)for(i=m=l+r>>1;i<=L;i++){V x;for(j=i-m;j<i;j+=j+s<i?s:1)x.push_back((j+s<i?v:a)[j]);l=M[x]++?n=i-m,m+1:l;}return V(&a[n],&a[n-1+l]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVNRb9owEH6ef4WlScWeE0ho07I4Du8T1d7ywtAUsrQ1S0xmB4ZasZ8@dnagsHVomrSHgeK7@@6@u8udUzSNf18Uu91rWTdL3SZz2ZqBaT8VjPUfUrQyUt3jTAASx@uyaJc6kapNeYbvSIZz@gQWrkTgaZH3jXwsCfWUt/AkQLU3EdozwnzRLdGUuyR13iSZZ3PcQpI1mVBvw@@WmnDJTDLhdD2VjM3E7XTjDpGRi3wqZ549mZnR2Tj@JjvGbb@oylxDySrRvErrcaxFTa1PilpUTKdpyGUiJpCc0acMd6UWQvo1XySSL5hYQFk5NnFIN/1mZR4@zvPiMyEdvI5zOl3MKK9cQ4yNleV6NQvjim912a60wq5F5VpUfsgqiN/u7GDqXCpC8RPC8LNAy53qJlFIhdP0AH19kFVJWt8/hB8oij@bp7QTOIO4hih6ROAlMQHyBd7g2HrpT9zNKXe5arGAbdoojl51cRZMEuvbL9VavQ@q97KGKwGBhxJ76sYxcO/X7vfuY64tcmIwwO/ydW4KLRuYU2naIjcl6nrMtebPM1Srel5q6HkYBB3qFg4eCWDAQSQ4CqwCS7fck712ZOqdgzuFsZeJQ5cY5JnMkp5tJrz5n7ohwOkFQYB9OyX8Bg9BC51tGz0CFA/w8B/0fbxjEE5Pv4A/XLO/umK/uV7b3QiNUAjvE@EbbOUVjlA4Qm/BDAC4xpfwRODo9JGznY7CwDHtY4P9cC/QFeDujy47DV27yEvIDpVQ9GxFrvr1Pr09o@/FXZXfm53/fvgD)

-3 thanks to @Unmitigated. -1 thanks to @movatica. -11 thanks to @ceilingcat. -2 thanks to @ceilingcat.

Mostly ungolfed:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using V=std::vector<int>;
V f(V a) {
    int l=0,r=a.size(),n,j,i,m,b,L=r,s=sqrt(r);
    std::map<V,int> M;
    V v(L);
    for(int i=0;i+s<L;i++) {
        V x(a.begin()+i,a.begin()+i+s);
        v[i]=M[x]=M[x]?M[x]:~i;
    }
    while (l<r) {
        m = (l+r)/2;
        b=0;
        std::set<V> S;
        for (i=m;i<=L;i++) {
            V x;
            for(j=i-m;j<i;j+=j+s<i?s:1)x.push_back((j+s<i?v:a)[j]);
            S.insert(x).second||(n=i-m,b=1);
        }
        b?l=m+1:r=m;
    }
    return V(a.begin()+n,a.begin()+n-1+l);
}
```

uses binary search, and sqrt decomposition for fast-ish substring comparison.

Takes a few seconds for the \$n=100000\$ case when compiled with `-O2`.

Comment: You can remove a few spaces: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `std::map<V,int>M;`.

Comment: oh wow I didn't think of square root decomposition would work

Comment: Converting the first `for` loop to `while` saves another byte: `while(i+s<L){V x(&a[i],&a[i+s]);v[i++]=M[x]=M[x]?M[x]:~i;}`